# how to exclude empty cells when Importing from excel?

Tags: import, excel

I am very new to mathematica and I need help importing excel file. The file that I am importing has a bunch of empty cells throughout the column and it is giving me some trouble taking an average of that data.

my importing commend is currently this:

```
DataConUpdraft815to818 = Import["/Users/JeffJeong/Desktop/QU_TMBV Data_08.14-08.19 2020 \mathe.xlsx", {"Data", 4, Range[80, 655], 9}]
```

and imported data is looking like this:
[image]

The problem is, I need to take a MeanAround of those numbers and this,,,, stuff (I assume it shows up when the cell is empty)is getting in the way, causing my code to look like this:
[image]
How do I exclude empty cells when I import from excel file? or how do I ignore empty cells when I am doing a MeanAround commend? As always, Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: did you try `DeleteCases[DataConUpdraft815to818, Null]`?

Comment: The empty cells import as empty strings. Replace the empty strings with [`Nothing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html): `data2 = data /. "" :> Nothing;`

Comment: @Rom38 DeleteCases didn't work.. or maybe I wasn't putting it in right;;

Comment: @BobHanlon where would I add that line into? sorry, I am very new to this...

Comment: @AJ12, try my previous proposition replacing `Null` to `Nothing`

Comment: After your `Import` the next line should be `DataConUpdraft815to818rev = DataConUpdraft815to818 /. "" :> Nothing` Give your data a new name in case you need to refer back to the original import.

Comment: @Rom38, sorry it didn't work..

Comment: @BobHanlon it worked!! thank you for the help!

Comment: @BobHanlon another question.. If I have number zero instead of empty cells and I would like to exclude those 0 values as well when I import. What would the commend look like in that case? And I would like that process to be done within the importing data command..

Comment: What have you tried and what were the results of those attempts?

Comment: @BobHanlon I just tried Select[Import[data],#(not equal sign)0&] and it worked! thanks for the reply though.

Comment: Since you are already doing replacements for empty strings, you could try the rule `/. {"" :> Nothing, 0. -> Nothing}`