# Ignoring or deleting empty cells from an Excel import

Tags: import, filtering, excel

I have tried all the possibilities with DeleteCases and everything at the answer in the closed question on the same subject

[how to exclude empty cells when Importing from excel?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/245171/how-to-exclude-empty-cells-when-importing-from-excel)

and checked my input repeatedly. I can make the content of the cells go away but not the empty elements themselves. I am reduced, in agony and embarrassment to sending a screenshot

[image: sceenshot]

Comment: OR after the second line you can write: ```/. { } -> Nothing``` now that I see you have null strings being imported. Please share feedback on which one works.

Comment: `{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {"", ""}, {}} //. {{"", ""} -> Nothing, {} -> 
   Nothing}`  : ReplaceRepeated would do the job after line 1 assuming that both items in empty list are null strings.

Comment: Your last one nailed it. Thanks!! Surprised Wolfram does not have an option for this as I suspect it is common.

Comment: Glad I could help. Be careful with ```""->Nothing``` or ```0->Nothing``` on their own. Pattern matching should be done on elements inside items that have already been imported as lists, otherwise every thing that matches the pattern will change to `Nothing`. Also `ReplaceRepeated` can result in an infinite loop, so read the docs for it.

Comment: If you look at the `FullForm` of the data (or some representative portion of it), you should be able to see exactly what the "empty" cells contain.

Comment: Another approach is `data = Cases[import, {_DateObject, __}]`.  In this case it is simpler to describe the good data instead of listing everything to ignore.